# How can I separate a list?

Tags: python

I have a list that contains a bunch of different list. ex. list = [['Hello world', '123', 'TGG'"], ["'Apple'", '321', 'EDF']]. When I print list[0], it prints out ['Hello world', '123', 'TGG'"], but I just want it to print out Hello world. How can I access this data?

```
import sys, csv

new_book = list()
result = []
new_result = []

with open ("book_data.txt", "r") as fin:
    r_file = fin.readlines()
    r_file.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
    for lines in r_file:
        temp = (lines.strip().split('|'))
        result.append(temp)

    print(new_result[0])
```

Comment: `print(list[0][0])`

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a good idea to not use [built-in functions in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) such as `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

You could access the first element in the nested list by using another set of brackets

```
print(new_result[0][0])
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I know this might have been a stupid question, but I am still new to coding and this helped out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Anthony's answer, if you wish to slice out some elements from a list of lists, a convenient way is to use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
    # Suppose we have a list of lists L as follows
    >>> L = [['Hello world', '123', 'TGG'], ['Apple', '321', 'EDF']]

    # This will extract the first item in each sublist
    >>> out = [l[0] for l in L]
    >>> print(out)
    ['Hello world', 'Apple']
```